# material ui and redux-form - how to implement submit validation

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I am using Redux Form and material UI to implement a registration page. My `onSubmit` function uses the fetch API to send a POST request to the server. If there is any server-related error (e.g duplicate email) the server returns an error response with some details about the rejected fields.

At this stage, I would like to display the errors in my form, but I can't get it to work. I tried throwing a SubmissionError, and throwing a JSON object. Is there any example online that I can follow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `asyncValidate` prop of `reduxForm` decorator.

**asyncValidate:**

```
const asyncValidate = (values, dispatch) => {
    // Your fetch request returns Promise object
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // I use setTimeout just to imitate latency from server
        setTimeout(() => {
            throw { emailNotUnique: 'Email should be unique' }
        }, 300)
    })
}
```

**reduxForm:**

```
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'yourFormName',
    asyncValidate: asyncValidate,
    asyncBlurFields: ['email']
})(YourForm)
```